# How to organize expanded tree properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

Using ReactJS, I create an array which contains fabric office365 components :

```
var userListItems = [];
for (let i of users) {
    userListItems.push(
        <DefaultButton >
            <Persona
                key = { i.imageInitials }
                name = { i.primaryText}
                imageUrl = { i.imageUrl }
                primaryText = { i.primaryText }
                size  = { personaSize }
                style = { personaStyle }
                onClick={this._chooseUser}
            />
        </DefaultButton>
    )
}

_chooseUser = (e) => {};
```

I want to add a handler onClick to every array item. Using it I want to get name, or key of item. Unfortunately I don't find these attributes in event object(`event.target.name`). How can I get data from these components?

Comment: either `onClick={this._chooseUser.bind(this, value)}` or `onClick={() => this._chooseUser(value)}` and `_chooseUser(value){console.log(value)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wrap this._chooseUser inside a function

```
var userListItems = [];

    for (let i of users){
        userListItems.push(
            <DefaultButton >
                <Persona
                    key = { i.imageInitials }
                    name = { i.primaryText}
                    imageUrl = { i.imageUrl }
                    primaryText = { i.primaryText }
                    size  = { personaSize }
                    style = { personaStyle }
                    onClick={()=>{this._chooseUser(i.imageInitials)}}
                />
            </DefaultButton>
        )
    }
```

_chooseUser = (e) => {
};